# Generic list with GWT AsyncDataProvider

Tags: java, gwt, generics

I have a GWT application where I need to work with multiple data types which are similar, but not quite the same. I want to display them using a CellList backed by an AsyncDataProvider. I'm trying to avoid creating multiple CellLists/AsyncDataProviders, so I'm trying to do this in a generic manner. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I've tried:

```
private AsyncDataProvider<MyInterface> myDataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<MyInterface>() {
            @Override
            protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<MyInterface> display) {

                AsyncCallback<Type> callback = new AsyncCallback<Type>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        myDataProvider.updateRowData(0, new ArrayList<MyImplementation>());    
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Type result) {
                        //some success logic               
                    }
                };
}
```

Which doesn't work because a collection of MyImplementation can't be substituted for a collection of MyInterface.

I've also tried:

```
private AsyncDataProvider<? extends MyInterface> myDataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<MyInterface>() {
                @Override
                protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<MyInterface> display) {

                    AsyncCallback<Type> callback = new AsyncCallback<Type>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                            myDataProvider.updateRowData(0, new ArrayList<MyImplementation>());    
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Type result) {
                            //some success logic               
                        }
                    };
    }
```

But I get the error: `"The method updateRowData(int, List<capture#2-of ? extends MyInterface>) in the type AsyncDataProvider<capture#2-of ? extends MyInterface> is not applicable for the arguments (int, ArrayList<MyImplementation>)"`

Any ideas? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do. There are alternatives, such as manually converting them all to a common type, but it just seems like a good use case for handling things in a generic fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Create a Generic Call Back, which takes a data provider and updates it as per your logic

```
public class HelloCallBack<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

private HelloDataProvider<T> dataProvider;

@Override
public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {

    dataProvider.updateRowData(0, new ArrayList<T>());

}

@Override
public void onSuccess(final T result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public HelloDataProvider<T> getDataProvider() {
    return dataProvider;
}

public void setDataProvider(final HelloDataProvider<T> dataProvider) {
    this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
}

}
```

now create a Data Provider which is also generic

```
public class HelloDataProvider<T> extends AsyncDataProvider<T> {

@Override
protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<T> display) {

    final HelloCallBack<T> callBack = new HelloCallBack<T>();
    callBack.setDataProvider(this);

}

}
```

now where ever you have to use the provider, instantiate it with the concrete types.

```
new HelloDataProvider<YourImplementation>();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I was hoping to achieve was using a single AsyncDataProvider and within that changing which callback is used depending on options the user selects. As I understand it, your solution will require multiple data provider implementations, so I'd need to switch which one is currently connected to the CellList. Also, each callback will require some custom logic.

Comment: It does not require multiple data provider "implementations", All you need to do is to write those two classes, It Just requires multiple data provider instantiations, (no different that creating a new List<Integer> or List<String>). Also to change the logic for each type, you can either create multiple types of callbacks or check for (result isInstanceOf YourImplementation) and process accordingly.